# Why is my model only updating if it is attached to an object? Angular

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I am trying to update a model with some radio buttons.  I have 2 different set of radio buttons and I can access only one of the updated models from the controller.  Here is my html:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <input ng-model="test.color" type="radio" value="red">
    </li>
    <li>
        <input ng-model="test.color" type="radio" value="blue">
    </li>
</ul>
    <tt>color = {{test.color | json}}</tt><br/>
<ul>
    <li>
        <input ng-model="color" type="radio" value="red">
    </li>
    <li>
        <input ng-model="color" type="radio" value="blue">
    </li>
</ul>
<tt>color = {{color | json}}</tt><br/>
<button ng-click="review()">Submit</button>
```

In my controller I just have a function, `review`, that has a `debugger` statement in it.  In the html,  when the top list is selected, it does not appear on the screen in the `<tt>`, but when the bottom one is selected, it does appear in the `<tt>`.

On the other hand, in the `review` function, the top radio button, `test.color` is attached to the `$scope`, but the bottom, `color`, is not attached to the `$scope`.  Why is this?

Comment: Are you getting any error messages in your console? For me, when this happens, it's because that value is not defined correctly in the scope.

Comment: I am not getting any errors.

Comment: In reality are you inside an ng-repeat? It should otherwise work. http://plnkr.co/edit/YLdY5rlmHVhPHfT2gk4c?p=preview

Comment: As it was said by [PSL](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1009603/psl) and [ABOS](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3979823/abos) this [code](http://plnkr.co/edit/KbBJdXkI4V1Y0OtxjBaS?p=preview) worked for me too, it is better to recreate the problem in a [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/) and post the link here so we could have a better idea on your problem.

Comment: I'm also not 100% sure what causes your problem. But is looks like  your HTML snippet is living is a child $scope of your controller's $scope. As objects are passed by reference you can see test.color, but not color.